# sed replacement by regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to achieve to generate with `sed` from  following source:

```
my_component_name_with_underlines_9.5.6

my_other_component_name_with_underlines_8.7.1
```

following target strings:

```
my_component_name_with_underlines_version = "9.5.6"

my_other_component_name_with_underlines_version = "8.7.1"
```

The logic could be like:

- find the last underline before a number and a dot appear
- append a `_version = "`  before the number
- append a last `"` at the end.

Thanks for any advice with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can just get the string after last underscore, make some replacements and print the result:

```
awk -F_ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} {a=$NF;$NF="version"; print $0" = \""a"\""}'
```

**N.B.** This will work with all **contemporary** version of `awk`

Comment: Hi Romeo Ninov
This does the job, seems awk is preferable for such tasks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
echo "my_component_name_with_underlines_9.5.6
my_other_component_name_with_underlines_8.7.1" | sed -E 's/(.*_)(.*)/\1version = "\2"/g' 

my_component_name_with_underlines_version = "9.5.6"
my_other_component_name_with_underlines_version = "8.7.1"
```

Replace `.*` with an unambiguous string to look for, as `.*` will match `any character any amount of times`.